# I have some doubts for the call and apply in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function a() {
    console.log(this === 1); //why it is false?
}
a.call(1);
```

when call or apply the function, the value be changed. orz!!

Comment: `this ` refers to object of the function not it's parameter

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call - ``thisArg.... and primitive values will be converted to objects.``. Resulting in object to primitive comparison in your function.

Comment: You pass `1` as a parameter although the function does not accept any parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the context with `call`, `bind` or `apply` using a primitive value, like a string, number of boolean, the resulting context will be a *boxed* version of the primitive.

If you log the value of `this` to the console, you'll see that rather than showing as `1`, it shows as something like `Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 1}`.

This boxed version is an object, so `===` will use reference equality to make the comparison — normally numbers would be compared by value, not reference.

You can create a safe number for comparison by passing the boxed version to the number constructor.

```
console.log(Number(this) === 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a primitive value is 'boxed' (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) it all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a strict comparison (===) and trying to compare an object with a number. Although you explicitly "1" the call function sends an object so the "1" on line four is an object. If you try the with a non strict comparison (==) it will evaluate to true as the value of 'this' will be coerced to be a number.